# Populate second text box value based on first textbox value after a click of a button using ajax and servlets

Tags: html, ajax, servlets

### The code that I have is working only in Internet Explorer , for the other browser the second textbox gets the value set as undefined

---

AjaxDemo.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Supreeth Vijay </title>
</head>
<body>
enter name :<input type="text" id="inputdisplay" size="26"/>
<button type="button" onclick="sendMessageToServer()">SEND TO SERVER </button><br/>
Reply Received :<input type="text" id="textdisplay" size="40"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
var request;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  
    request=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }  
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){  
    request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
    }  



function sendMessageToServer()

{

    request.onreadystatechange = receiveMessageFromServer;

    request.open("POST","AjaxDemo?name="+document.getElementById('inputdisplay').value,true);



    request.send();

    document.getElementById('inputdisplay').value="";


}

function receiveMessageFromServer()
{

    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)

        {
        document.getElementById('textdisplay').value = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")[0].text;
        }


}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

AjaxDemo.java (Servlet)

```
  package com.ServletAjax;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AjaxDemo
 */
@WebServlet("/AjaxDemo")
public class AjaxDemo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AjaxDemo() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("server received the following message from client"+request.getParameter("name"));
        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.getWriter().println("<responseFromServer>hi"+request.getParameter("name")+"</responseFromServer>");
        System.out.println("server replied with follwoing message"+request.getParameter("name"));

    }

}
```

Code is implemented using Ajax and Servlets

1. Currently the program is working fine in Internet Explorer
2. The Second textbox after the click of the button is set to undefined in other browsers
3. Required output is to populate the the second textbox with the value entered in first textbox after onclick of the button in other browsers like mozillafirefox ,chrome,opera,netscape navigator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below line.
document.getElementById('textdisplay').value = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("responseFromServer")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;